# Passing many different classes to one method C#

Tags: c#

Hello I have methods like below:

```
    public EventItemPage LaunchItemsActionByRowIndex(int RowIndex)
    {
        // does some other stuff

        var eventItemPage = new EventItemPage(driver);
        eventItemPage.WaitForPageToLoad();

        return eventItemPage;
    }

    public StandardSalesforcePage LaunchViewActionByRowIndex(int RowIndex, string actionItem)
    {
        // Does the same as above method

        var bookDetailPage = new StandardSalesforcePage(driver);
        bookDetailPage.WaitForPageToLoad();

        return bookDetailPage;
    }
```

I would like to combine these two methods and pass the class in as a parameter and move them to a new class that will be inherited by the classes listed above.  I would need to access some methods on the classes and also also make sure the constructor is called.  I have attempted to use the create instance activator like below but do not think I am using it properly.

```
object obj = (yourPage)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(StringBuilder), yourPage);
```

I have been researching quite a bit however I am quite confused if this is possible or not. I failed to mention above that we pass an instance of selenium driver to the constructor of the classes we would be using.

Comment: "that will be inherited by the classes listed above" -- you haven't listed any classes anywhere.

Comment: Perhaps it is a solution to write a little class with the objecttypes you need as member? Then you can send an instance of your class with both needed objects as parameter to your function/method

Comment: You could define a `generic method` and inject the needed `object` instead of creating it with the `Activator`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx

Comment: You could also use an interface which the two objects implement as the 'object' return from the method.

Comment: Create one base class with method WaitForPageToLoad and inherit StandardSalesforcePage and EventItemPage from it and override the method. Change LaunchViewActionMethod to return the base class object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not impossible to do what you ask, but you'll need to slightly rework how your classes work.

You cannot enforce a constructor with parameters on a class, but you can enforce that it has a *parameterless* constructor:

```
public T LaunchFooByRowIndex<T>(int RowIndex, string actionItem = String.Empty) where T : IFoo, new()
{
    // does some other stuff

    T myObject = new T();
    myObject.LoadDriver(driver);
    myObject.WaitForPageToLoad();

    return myObject;
}
```

Note that I made the second parameter optional in order for both method signatures to be compatible.

By mentioning `new()`, you make sure that you can only work with classes that have a parameterless constructor (and also implement `IFoo`). When dealing with generic types, you can call a parameterless constructor (assuming you required its existence).

But you'll need to set up your classes as follows:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void LoadDriver(Driver driver);
    void WaitForPageToLoad();
}

public class MyFooClass : IFoo
{
    //parameterless constructor exists implicitly,
    //UNLESS you have defined constructors with parameters.
    //In that case, you need to explicitly make a parameterless constructor.

    //and then you implement your interface methods here
}
```

---

**Addendum**

There are other ways to do this.

You can use inheritance instead of interfaces. That allows you to have a single implementation for shared logic (e.g. if `WaitForPageToLoad()` does the exact same thing for both of your classes).
But unless I'm mistaken, then you lose out on the clean parameterless constructor like I used in my example.

Comment: Thank you I will give this a try

Comment: @NicolePhillips Happy to help :)